# How to write an inline for loop in python after another instruction?

Tags: python, for-loop, command-line

Starting with `for` works

```
root@messagerie-secours[10.10.10.19] /home/serveur # python -c "for x in xrange(10):print x;"
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
root@messagerie-secours[10.10.10.19] /home/serveur #
```

If you have for in the middle, it's a syntax error :

```
root@messagerie-secours[10.10.10.19] /home/serveur # python -c "a=2;for x in xrange(10):print x;"
  File "<string>", line 1
    a=2;for x in xrange(10):print x;
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
root@messagerie-secours[10.10.10.19] /home/serveur #
```

Is it possible to get rid of that syntax error ?

Comment: No, it isn't possible to remove the syntax error and to still use a for loop whilst being inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Woo, plenty of solutions! here some others:

```
python -c 'print "\n".join(map(str, xrange(10)))'

python <<"EOF"
for x in range(10):
  print x
EOF

echo $'a=12\nfor x in range(a): print x' | python
```

Comment: Nice ! also, thrid one can also be written like this (tested, working) : `python -c $'a=2\nfor x in xrange(1,10):\n    print x'`

Answer (score 2):

Writing mutlitple statements and control structures in one line is not a good idea, since Python heavily depends on indentation.

You can place your code correctly indented in a `loop.py` file and you should be fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/nev python

a = 2
for x in xrange(10):
    print x
```

Run it with `python loop.py`.

If you really need the program written in the command line, try this:

```
root@messagerie-secours[10.10.10.19] /home/serveur # python -c "
> a = 2
> for x in range(10) :
>     print x
> "
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the underlying OS. It will be easy on an Unix-like :

```
python -c "a=5
for i in range(a): print i"
```

correctly gives

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

on my FreeBSD system, because Unix shells allow newline between quotes.

But AFAIK, it is not possible in Windows CMD shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.count` which will yields 0, 1, 2, ....

With `__import__`, you can do it in one line:

```
python -c 'for x in __import__("itertools").count(): print x'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me on Python 2.7:

```
python -c "exec('\n'.join(['a=42', 'for x in xrange(10):', '  print x', 'print a']))"
```

Giving the output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
42
```

Comment: Isn't exec usually a bad idea ?

Comment: Yes, but this is known input so should be relatively safe.